# Submit spark application in a Jar file separate from uber Jar containing all dependencies

Tags: maven, hadoop, apache-spark, jar, uberjar

I am building Spark application which has several heavy dependencies (e.g. Stanford NLP with language models) so that uber Jar that contains application code with dependencies takes ~500MB. Uploading this fat Jar to my test cluster takes a lot of time and I decided to build my app and dependencies into separate Jar files.

I've created two modules in my parent pom.xml and build app and uber jar separately with `mvn package` and `mvn assembly:asembly` respectively.

However, after I upload these separate jars to my YARN cluster application fails with the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.hadoop.net.unix.DomainSocketWatcher.(I)V     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.shortcircuit.DfsClientShmManager.(DfsClientShmManager.java:415)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.shortcircuit.ShortCircuitCache.(ShortCircuitCache.java:379)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.ClientContext.(ClientContext.java:100)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.ClientContext.get(ClientContext.java:151)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:690)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:601)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2653)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:92)

When running application on Spark it also fails with similar error.

Jar with dependencies is included into Yarn classpath:

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
    <value>
      $HADOOP_CONF_DIR,
      $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/*,
      $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/lib/*,
      $HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/*,
      $HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/lib/*,
      $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/*,
      $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/lib/*,
      $YARN_HOME/*,
      $YARN_HOME/lib/*,
      /usr/local/myApp/org.myCompany.myApp-dependencies.jar
    </value>
  </property>
```

Is it actually possibly to run Spark application this way? Or I have to put all dependencies on YARN (or Spark) classpath as individual Jar files?

Comment: Are those dependencies available to all worker nodes?

Comment: Yes, they are. org.myCompany.myApp-dependencies.jar is uploaded to all worker nodes and added to YARN classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with my spark job. This is a dependency issue for sure. You have to make sure the correct versions are picked up at runtime.The best way to do this was adding the correct version hadoop-common-2.6.jar to my application jar. I also upgraded my hadoop-hdfs version in application jar. This resolved my issue.